# Building 7 Transistor Logic Gates using And, Or, Exor and Inverter

Tags: inverter, nand

Hello I just want to know something..

For example, I have this:
[image]

Let's say I  build an AND Gate and an Inverter.. I check the and gate if it satisfies the truth table and upon checking it, it works. Same with inverter...

This time I'll be combining the And and the inverter to produce a Nand Gate.. upon doing it, it works again. therefore we have the nand gate out of the two combination of AND,OR gate..

Here's the question..

Since I already have the NAND gate, I want to check again for the AND gate without removing the combination of the AND and Inverter (NAND) .. Just for the AND Gate.. How I'll be doing it??

Comment: Am I missing something? Just probe the connection between the two gates!

Comment: If you are referring  to your two-transistor AND gate (see previous questions): electrically, there is no separate AND gate in it.

Comment: Just add one more inverter, which will then give you the output of the and gate

Answer (score 3):

Just check it same as before.  The signal between the AND gate and inverter is still there, whether it drives the inverter input or not.

By the way, real NAND gates aren't always made with a AND gate and inverter.  Take a look at the circuit of a TTL NAND gate and you will see it is all one circuit that directly produces the NAND function.  A TTL AND gate is roughly a NAND gate with a additional inverting output stage.

There are many ways to use various different types of transistors to realize the common 2-input 1-output logic gates.  Do not a assume that a NAND is more complicated than a AND, or vice versa.  The same is true for OR and NOR, and other gates.